# Clipping widget only vertically

Tags: flutter

I have a `ListView.builder` that contains `Container`s with blurred shadows.  By default, the `ListView` clips the edges, which means my shadows get clipped.  If I remove the clip on the `Listview` by using `clipBehavior: Clip.none`, the `Listview` then scrolls items vertically beyond the bounds of the `ListView`.

Is there a way that I can clip the `ListView` only vertically, leaving the shadows intact horizontally?

Comment: can you include sample code-snippet that will reproduce the same error

Comment: I recommend you to use `CustomScrollView` with `scrollDirection: Axis.vertical`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `ClipPath`:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return ClipPath(
               clipper: VerticalClipper(),
               child: ListView(),
      );
  }
```

And then implement VerticalClipper:

```
class VerticalClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    Path path = Path();
    path.moveTo(-double.maxFinite, 0);
    path.lineTo(double.maxFinite, 0);
    path.lineTo(double.maxFinite, size.height);
    path.lineTo(-double.maxFinite, size.height);
    path.close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

That creates a rectangle with the height matching the height of your ListView and the width as wide as possible.